# Why neo vim is displaying $ at the very end of line and > at the beginnings of line

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vim, parrot-os, neovim

[image]

Why `neovim` is displaying these special characters at the beginning and at the end of line?

I have uninstalled and reinstall `neovim` but this didn't fixed the issue.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like [`listchars`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27), pseudo-characters used to more clearly see certain whitespace characters, such as tabs and newlines. Especially useful for distinguishing between tabs and spaces and making sure there isn't any trailing whitespace.

You can toggle their display using [`set list!`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27list%27), or just turn them off with `set nolist`.

Comment: But when I reopen the vim its still displaying those characters. Is there a way by which I can enable this by default so don't have to execute the `set nolist` command?

Comment: @Udesh [`:verbose set list?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585591/3342206) should tell you which file last set `list`. Note that you'll want to start up a new instance of neovim so it won't be misled by any changes you've entered manually.

Comment: When I executed `:verbose set list?` in `neovim` it displayed **~/.config/nvim/init.vim** and added `set nolist` at the end of the **init.vim** file and this fixed the special character displaying issue .